# Как в JS достать сессию?

Tags: java, сессия, servlet, javascript

Задача:
Есть метод, допустим:

```
public void getVal(HttpServletRequest req){
 this.myfield = req.getSession().getId();
}
```

В `JS` должен вызываться метод:

```
$.getVal(/*тут то что я хочу узнать от вас жители http://hashcode.ru*/);
```

Как в `JS` достать сессию?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Печатаете в JSP, в скрытых полях, данные сессии, которые вам нужны. Затем при помощи JS извлекаете от туда данные.

Comment: сейчас проверю)а пока ругаюсь на себя за то, что сам не додумался(

Answer (score 3):

Смотря что Вы подразумеваете под словом "Сессии". Если Вы имеете ввиду серверную (например, сайта написанного на `php`) сессию, то Вы ее не достанете, Вы только можете получить ее идентификатор из `cookies` браузера.